# Is jqueryscript.net pages generated automatically?

Tags: github

I recently created a jQuery plugin and pushed in github.com. 
Next day (or few hour later) I found in github traffic some referral from jqueryscript.net, I click the referral and they have a page about my plugin with description and demo.
Did they generated the page automatically or they manually searched new plugins everyday and create the page and demo?
Just curious because that is really fast.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer that except the people behind that site.

Answer (score 2):

On the [website](http://www.jqueryscript.net/about/), it states:

> Please note that all the resources are gathered by users and public sources on the internet.

It's rather ambiguous, but it *might* mean that only the users find the plugins.